# Drop a pin to location on the line between 2 points in MapView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, location, mapkit

I have a problem: I have **a store location** and **1 pin annotation** with Radius = 2km. When user move the pin annotation exceed to radius 2km from store location. I want to jump the pin on the line from store location and old pin annotation **in order to the circle radius always cover the store location**. How can I do that? Please give me some advice. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the store location covered means constraining the pin within a 2km circle around around the store. If the store is at (0,0) and your point at (dx,dy), then find the distance:
   R=sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy).

Now if R>2km, find the factor to scale the distance by: 
  s = 2km/R.

Now move the point to (s * dx, s * dy), which will be exactly on the 2km circle around the store, so the store will be on the 2km circle around the pin.